# How to get the absolute string from a name-spaced Django URL?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

You know how in a Django app, you can redirect to a different view using a simple function in your views? Its usually something like this:

```
return redirect('myapp:my_url')
```

The above redirect would redirect me to an absolute URL which could be something like this:

https://example.com/my-url/

Now, my question is, how can I get the https://example.com/my-url/ as a string using a function in my view? I don't want to redirect, I just want to get it, and save it in my variable.

So, by doing something like this:

```
print my_function('myapp:my_url')
```

We would get an output in the terminal like so:

> https://example.com/my-url/

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Does this do the trick for you?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_absolute_url

Comment: Actually, I think you want: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.reverse

Answer (score 1):

You can get the "path" element of the URL (ie `/my-url/`) using the [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.reverse) function you have already mentioned.

The domain of the website can be added using [`request.build_absolute_uri()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri).

```
print(request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('myapp:my_url'))
```

Note that I'm using the Python 3 print syntax for this example.